# Accessing variables without using global express request module

Tags: json, express, request

I am currently building an express app with the request module getting data from an API. However, I want to pass this data to a res.render function without creating a global variable. Even when creating the global, it will console.log an updated one first, before it would update the view on the site. I'm just wondering how I should go about doing this and getting the data to be passed into the res.render function. Thank you.

```
var pounds = {};


exports.index = function(req, res) {
request(options, function(err, res, body) {
if (!err && res.statusCode === 200)  {  
let info = JSON.parse(body);
pounds = ("£"+info.GBP);
console.log(pounds)

};
});
res.render('pages/index', {british: pounds});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your call to `res.render` to *within* the inner callback, and use a local variable. Also be sure not to shadow your outer `res` with an inner one (I've renamed the inner one `response` below).

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    request(options, function(err, response, body) {
        if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
            let info = JSON.parse(body);
            let pounds = "£" + info.GBP;
// Local -------^
            res.render('pages/index', {    // Moved to within
                british: pounds            // the inner
            });                            // callback
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: @t-j-crowder thanks for your answer Tj, however it will then throw this error 
     TypeError: res.render is not a function

Comment: @zak: Ah, I didn't notice you shadowed your outer `res` with an inner one. Just rename one of them. I've updated the above to rename the inner one.